# How to pass input from app.R to other script and return objects?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have two files `app.R` and `LoanHealthv2.R`

app.R has following code. I am taking `noc` as input name which I need to pass as input to `LoanHealthv2.R` file and compute the results so that I can use the results of `LoanHealthv2.R` file in this app.

Also how can I make it reactive so that everytime I select different `noc` it generates new results?

```
########################## Ui function ################################

ui=fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Loan Health"),

  fluidRow(
    selectInput("noc","Name of Customer", customers[,1], selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
                selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
  ),


  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("Plot", width = "100%", height = "400px", click = NULL,
               dblclick = NULL, hover = NULL, hoverDelay = NULL,
               hoverDelayType = NULL, brush = NULL, clickId = NULL,
               hoverId = NULL, inline = FALSE)
  )
)

########################## server function ################################

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$Plot<-renderPlot({

    customer<-input$noc #Name of customer

    plot(SalesClientData$Date,SalesClientData$DPD,type="l")

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`LoanHealthv2.R` looks like this

```
customer = "A1"   #<-I want this to be equal to input `noc` from app.R and compute the result below and make it available so that I can plot output.

account<-customers[which(customers[,1]==customer), 2] 
start<- customers[which(customers[,1]==customer), 3]

SalesClientData = subset(POSData,POSData$Loan_Account_Number==account)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand fully what you are trying to do, but you could use a combination of  `reactiveValues` and `source` in your application.

```
########################## Ui function ################################

ui=fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Loan Health"),

  fluidRow(
    selectInput("noc","Name of Customer", customers[,1], selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,
                selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
  ),


  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("Plot", width = "100%", height = "400px", click = NULL,
               dblclick = NULL, hover = NULL, hoverDelay = NULL,
               hoverDelayType = NULL, brush = NULL, clickId = NULL,
               hoverId = NULL, inline = FALSE)
  )
)

########################## server function ################################

server <- function(input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  output$Plot<-renderPlot({

    customer<-input$noc #Name of customer
    rv$customer <- customer
    plot(SalesClientData$Date,SalesClientData$DPD,type="l")

  })
  source("LoanHealthv2.R", local = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Then in your `LoanHealthv2.R` file, you could make the appropriate changes:

```
#Assuming you want to output this as a table using the `DT` package

output$CustomerDF <- renderDT ({
req(rv$customer)
customer = rv$customer   

account<-customers[which(customers[,1]==customer), 2] 
start<- customers[which(customers[,1]==customer), 3]

SalesClientData = subset(POSData,POSData$Loan_Account_Number==account)

datatable(SalesClientData)

})
```